# Single configuration file for multiples applications

Tags: vb.net, configuration-files

I have multiple `console` applications each one has an `app.config` file, this way is a little impractical because if I need to change the email server configuration I have to make the change in all the `app.config` files, I want to create a single configuration file or something similar so I can have all the configuration in a single place.

which is the best way to achive this? I was thinking in a `xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I have one way of doing it.  First, you change your app.config file so that the appSettings is pulled from a separate file.  Replace the entire appSettings section with the following :

```
<appSettings file="myappsettings.config"/>
```

Then you need to create the myappSettings.config file.  You can create this new file anywhere.   I keep it in the root of the Solution folder.  Include everything that was in the appSettings section, including the opening and closing tags in the file.

Then, in each project, add the new myappsettings.config [file as an existing item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9f4t9t92%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  It will link the new config file to your project and copy it to the project output at compile time.

When you need to change settings, just change the appSettings in myappsettings.config.